How to activate a Menu using a state variable without clicking on it?
I'm developing an application using SwiftUI and I've encountered a scenario where I would like to open a context menu automatically without needing to click on it. I have a state variable that changes value when a TextField is being edited, and I would like the context menu to open automatically when the TextField is in editing mode. Is there any way to achieve this in SwiftUI?
ZStack(alignment: .trailing) {
    HStack {
        TextField("00:00", text: $customTime, onEditingChanged: { editing in
            self.isEditing = editing
        })
        .textFieldStyle(.plain)
        Spacer()
        Image(systemName:  "timer")
            .resizable()
            .frame(width: 15, height: 15)
            .foregroundStyle((isHovered && !isEditing) ? Color(.darkGray) : (isEditing ? Color(.lightDarkerGreen) : Color(.gray)))
    }
    .padding(.vertical, 20)
    .padding(.horizontal, 16)
    .background(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 12).strokeBorder((isHovered && !isEditing) ? Color(.darkGray) : (isEditing ? Color(.lightDarkerGreen) : Color(.gray)), lineWidth: 2)) // cor do stroke com base em isHovered ou isEditing
    
    // MENU
    Menu {
        Section(header: Text("Sugestões")) {
            ForEach(timeStamps, id: \.self) { time in
                Button("\(String(time)) minutos") {
                    selectedSortByOption = time
                    customTime = formatTime(time)
                }
            }
        }
    } label: {
        EmptyView()
    }
    .frame(width: 50, height: 50)
    .background(Color.clear)
    .menuStyle(.borderlessButton)
    .menuIndicator(.hidden)
    .padding(.trailing, 5)
}

The Reminders app has the functionality that I want
I tried using .contextMenu but in only works if I right-Click it.

There is the popover(isPresented:attachmentAnchor:arrowEdge:content:) modal presentation, which takes a state variable for its isPresented attribute.
In your example, you could use it like this:
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var customTime: String = ""
    @State private var timeStamps: [String] = ["00:00", "00:15", "00:30", "00:45", "01:00"]
    
    @State private var isEditing: Bool = false
    @State private var isHovered: Bool = false
    
    func formatTime(_ time: String) -> String {
        return time
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack(alignment: .trailing) {
            HStack {
                TextField("00:00", text: $customTime, onEditingChanged: { editing in
                    self.isEditing = editing
                })
                .textFieldStyle(.plain)
                Spacer()
                Image(systemName:  "timer")
                    .resizable()
                    .frame(width: 15, height: 15)
                    .foregroundStyle((isHovered && !isEditing) ? Color(.darkGray) : (isEditing ? Color(.green) : Color(.gray)))
            }
            .padding(.vertical, 20)
            .padding(.horizontal, 16)
            .background(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 12).strokeBorder((isHovered && !isEditing) ? Color(.darkGray) : (isEditing ? Color(.green) : Color(.gray)), lineWidth: 2))
            
            .popover(isPresented: $isEditing, arrowEdge: .bottom) {
                Section(header: Text("Sugestões")) {
                    ForEach(timeStamps, id: \.self) { time in
                        Button("\(String(time)) minutos") {
                            // selectedSortByOption = time
                            customTime = formatTime(time)
                        }
                        .buttonStyle(.plain)
                    }
                }
                .background(Color.clear)
                .padding(.trailing, 5)
                .padding()
            }
        }
    }
}

